# Copy or move libs after build with cmake

Tags: cmake

In my project there is a folder that contains third party libraries (google test, zlib, ...). I want to put the libraries in a common folder when all this libraries are built. I'm trying to do this with cmake but I'm having problems. I'm trying this code:

```
add_subdirectory(gtest-1.6.0)    
add_custom_command(
            TARGET gtest_main 
            POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${SRC_LIB_DIR}/*.a ${DST_LIB_DIR})
```

I think the problem could be that the target gtest main in not defined at this level but in a lower level

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you set the `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable in your CMakeLists.txt before calling `add_subdirectory` (and the subproject does not override it), libraries should fall into the right place.

Additionally like this the target in the subproject keeps their dependency to the output-file. Which wouldn't work with your copy - the target would be always out-of-date and thus rebuilt.

EDIT: I overlooked that your copy-command is copying .a-files and thanks to @Fraser's comment I learned as well that `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` should to do the trick.

Comment: Does not work. Making this code: SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/third_party/lib/release") and then adding gtest subdirectory, does nothing. The libraries go always to gtest directory root.

Comment: Since gtest builds `STATIC` libs by default, you want to set the [`CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt:ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) rather than `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` which is for `SHARED` libs.

Comment: Thanks Fraser and Patrick. CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY did the trick. Thanks to both!!

Comment: fwiw I had to set all of them; https://bytefreaks.net/programming-2/manually-set-the-cmake-output-folder